# Error: message: "column \"s\" does not exist" with a json field result from postgres query

Tags: json, postgresql, rust, serde

While enabling the features `["with-serde_json-1", "array-impls"]`, I'm trying to obtain the json result from postgres so i can iterate.

As tested the query from my client, it works perfectly but integrating into rust-postgres, I have the above error:

here is the complete error I had:

```rs
: thread 'main' panicked at 'Failed to execute the query: Error { kind: Db, cause: Some(DbError { severity: "ERROR", parsed_severity: Some(Error), code: SqlState(E42703), message: "column \"s\" does not exist", detail: None, hint: None, position: Some(Original(1369)), where_: None, schema: None, table: None, column: None, datatype: None, constraint: None, file: Some("parse_relation.c"), line: Some(3393), routine: Some("errorMissingColumn") }) }', src/main.rs:47:48
```

here is the complete code:

```rs
extern crate postgres;
use postgres::{Client, NoTls};

fn main() {

     // Replace these with your actual database connection details
    let db_url = "postgresql://postgres:mypass@localhost/users";

    // Connect to the PostgreSQL database
    let mut client = Client::connect(db_url, NoTls).expect("Failed to connect to the database");
    let schema = "public";
    // Define the SQL query
    let query = r#"
        select row_to_json(Tb) as tbls from(
        SELECT T."table_name", (select json_agg(col) from (
        SELECT "column_name", udt_name, is_nullable, data_type, column_default FROM
        information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = T."table_name" AND column_default NOT LIKE 'nextval%%'
        ) col ) as cols,

        (select json_agg(colx) from (
        SELECT "column_name", udt_name, is_nullable, data_type, column_default FROM
        information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = T."table_name"
        ) colx ) as identifiable_columns,

        (select json_agg(colr) from (
        SELECT
            tc.table_name,
            kcu.column_name,
            ccu.table_name AS foreign_table_name,
            ccu.column_name AS foreign_column_name
        FROM
            information_schema.table_constraints AS tc
            JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu
              ON tc.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name
              AND tc.table_schema = kcu.table_schema
            JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage AS ccu
              ON ccu.constraint_name = tc.constraint_name
              AND ccu.table_schema = tc.table_schema
        WHERE tc.constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY' AND tc.table_name=T."table_name"
        ) colr ) as relates
        FROM information_schema.tables as T
        WHERE table_schema=%s) Tb;
    "#;

    // Execute the query and collect the results
    let rows = client.query(query, &[&schema]).expect("Failed to execute the query");
    println!("{:#?}", rows);

  }
```

Answer (score 4):

`%s` is *not* how you specifiy parameters for a query, and you shouldn't use string interpolation anyways, it's very insecure if the data comes from the user. According to the [documentation](https://docs.rs/postgres/0.19.7/postgres/struct.Client.html#method.query) replacing it with `$1` should work.